Getting a Missing API declaration after sending my app to Apple for review
I finally deployed my react-native on expo-cli app to production on Appstore, and then Apple hit me with this
ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “MagicMusicCreateAISongs” file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace...

ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “MagicMusicCreateAISongs” file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp...

ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “MagicMusicCreateAISongs” file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategorySystemBootTime. ..

ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “MagicMusicCreateAISongs” file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories: NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults...

I added these to my app.json but I'm still getting the issue.
"ios": {
      "privacyManifests": {
        "NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes": [
          {
            "NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType": "NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults",
            "NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons": [
              "CA92.1"
            ]
          },
          {
            "NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType": "NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace",
            "NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons": [
              "85F4.1"
            ]
          },
          {
            "NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType": "NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp",
            "NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons": [
              "DDA9.1"
            ]
          },
          {
            "NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType": "NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategorySystemBootTime",
            "NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons": [
              "35F9.1"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },

How do I resolve this, please?

Did you upgrade to a RN version that has a privacy manifest?

Have you checked it actually generates the correct xcprivacy file?

@tomerpacific I just started the project about a week ago

@NooblantisDistrict - https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/discussions/776
